# Explaination of von Neumann minimax theorem

Tags: game-theory

I don't really understand minimax theorem. I have watched this video [minimax in chess](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzsnQ1a9fq0) and I understand that by backward induction as first player I can find best outcome for me (minimize my loss = minimize opponent's gain) but I don't get that equation (got from wikipedia) bellow. Can someone explain me it or recommend some nice video?

$$ \max_{x\in X} \min_{y\in Y} f(x,y) = \min_{y\in Y} \max_{x\in X} f(x,y) $$

Comment: What is it about the equation that you don't understand? Also, notice that this is, in general not true. There are important hypotheses on $X$, $Y$ and $f$.

Comment: the left hand part of equation says "find $y$ for which $f$ is the lowest for $P_2$, and if 
 there are multiple choices find $x$ for which $f$ is the greatest for $P_1$" - is it right? What does the right part of equation mean? Is it still from 1st player perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following two sequencial games:

Game A: Player 1 chooses $x$, announces it. Then Player 2 chooses $y$.

Game B: Player 2 chooses $y$, announces it. Then Player 1 chooses $x$.

For any given $x$ in game A, the problem of Player 2 is to minimize $f(x,y)$. So the payoff will be $g(x)=\min_y f(x,y)$. Among all these possible options, Player 1 chooses the one that maximizes $g(x)$, so the total payoff is $\max_x \min_y f(x,y)$.

With a similar argument, the payoff in Game B is $\min_y \max_x f(x,y)$.

Clearly, in Game A player 2 has an advantage relative to the simultaneous game and to Game B, so $\max\min f\leq \min\max f$.

The minimax theorem states (with appropriate assumptions of $f,x,y$) that they are equal, so it doesn't matter who announces his strategy first (or if they play at the same time) the result is the same. Hence, we can actually play the strategies we wanted to announce in the simultaneous game (these are called the optimal strategies) and get this value.

Comment: Here as payoff we understand one value (for example playoff is 5, not (5,-2) or (0,3)), and Player 1 wants payoff to be as high as it can, while Player 2 wants payoff to be as low as it can be. In your example $g(x)$ is something like subgame/subtree, so in game A Player 1 with backward induction finds best outcome depending on player 2 most possible response, and in game B Player 2 "becomes Player 1", but he is still looking for lowest payoff. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. It considers only one payoff (zerosum)

Comment: And that $\max\min f = \min \max f$ I can read as $\max\min f_A = \min \max f_B$ because those games are almost symetric (just the order of players changes, $f_A = f_B$)?

Comment: If I'm following you then yes. The payoffs are the same in the game, only the order of choosing actions is different.